# Drone.io Docker Plugin Daemon Configuration

Tags: docker-registry, drone.io

How does one add a daemon.json (docker daemon configuration file) to the drone.io instance, so the image tag on pipeline steps can be configured to be used with private registries and client certificates?

Answer (score 0):

For some of our private network procedures we have a simple Registry running. In your case you need to add the `daemon.json` file in both master and worker nodes.

This is the `/etc/docker/dameon.json`

```
{
    "insecure-registries" : ["internalregistry.example.com"],
}
```